# Number divisible by product of its digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n = \overline{abcde1}$. Prove that if n is divisible by the product of its digits, then at
> least two among the digits a, b, c, d, e are equal.

I haven't got much farther on this problem than simply doing $abcde|10^5a+10^4b+10^3c+10^2d+10^1e+10^0$. This implies that $a|10^4b+10^3c+10^2d+10e+1$, and similarly for the others, but I can't get much further.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Show that $a, b, c, d, e$ are all odd.

Then apply PP.

Comment: It takes a little more than this — $a,b,c,d,e$ could be some permutation of $1,3,5,7,9$. But in that case, the product of digits is divisible by 9, and...

Comment: Thanks, what is PP?

Comment: @TheMathematologist Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Right, I consider these cases of dealing with "n holes and n pigeons implies we have 1 pigeon in each hole, after which there's an immediate contradiction" to also be a pretty direct application of PP.